# CodeIgniter Route found but gives 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ive been battling with codeigniter routes for days. and it has seriously held back my productivity. Thus, any help here would be very much appreciated.

I have a login form:

- if login incorrect redirect -> failed page
- if login correct redirect -> welcome

Im using codeigniter route debugger script, to check and debug my routes.

When I check my routing logs the following shows, for a correct login attempt.

> DEBUG - 2018-05-11 03:40:10 --> Client sent : users/welcome
>
> DEBUG - 2018-05-11 03:40:10 --> Route found : users/welcome  --> users/welcome
>
> DEBUG - 2018-05-11 03:40:10 --> Redirecting to : users/welcome -->users/welcome
>
> users/welcome DEBUG - 2018-05-11 03:40:10 --> Global POST, GET and
>
> COOKIE data sanitized ERROR - 2018-05-11 03:40:10 --> **404 Page Not**

As you can see the route is found and then it redirects to the route BUT then somehow it results in a 404 page not found.

However I clearly have a welcome page in my views as can be seen on image below:

[image]

I stripped everything and tried to make my routes as simple as possible. `config/routes.php` reads as follow.

```
$route['users']= 'users';
$route['users/index'] = 'users/index';
$route['users/login'] ='users/login';
$route['users/welcome'] ='users/welcome';
$route['users/failed'] ='users/failed';

$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/index/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Page URL reads as follow: http://mysite/users/welcome = 404 error as described above.

Any help appreciated.

**Additional Info: Controller Users()**

public function login(){
    $data['title'] = 'Sign In';

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('users/login', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
} else {

    // Get username
   echo $username = $this->input->post('username');
    // disabled encryption for testing
   echo $password = $this->input->post('password');

    // Login user
    $user_id = $this->users_model->login($username, $password);

    if($user_id){
        // Create session
        $user_data = array(
            'userID' => $user_id,
            'username' => $username,
            'logged_in' => true
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

        // Set message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'You are now logged in');

            redirect('users/welcome');
    } else {
        // Set message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login is invalid');
            redirect('users/failed');

    }
}
```

Comment: did you check your `$user_id` variable? `var_dump($user_id)`

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov ok give me one min todo it. and report back. But what has this todo with routes though? Thanks

Comment: Where's the methods `welcome' and 'failed' in your users class that calls the views?

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov I added var_dump($user_id) entered the correct credentials and logged in. But I then get redirect to : `http://mysite/users/welcome` AND then the 404 page and nothing displays for the `vardump`.

However I took out the redirect in the controller for successful login. And the `$_user_id` got displayed correctly on the login page (since I removed the redirect) I also did `$var_dump($_SESSION)` and all info got displayed correctly. 

Hope that makes sense. Thanks for the help

Comment: @FriderichWeber I think you found it and I am now banging my head against the wall. I have no methods `welcome` and `failed` UGH is that the problem? Where should I add these methods? Thank you

Comment: I'm adding an answer,  just a moment.

Comment: You just set routes and didn't create a methods??? Man I thought if you have a route then you have a methods too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each route maps to a controller, not a view.

You don't need to define your routes when they map specifically to the controller class and method.  IE: `http://website.com/users/login` "magically" maps to `Users` Controller `login` method.

You only need to define routes when you get creative.

So here's the short of your Users class (controller)

#### Routes

```
// You don't need these for your current usage
$route['users']= 'users';
$route['users/index'] = 'users/index';
$route['users/login'] ='users/login';
$route['users/welcome'] ='users/welcome';
$route['users/failed'] ='users/failed';

// keep these below.
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/index/$1'; //<-- this will give you problems probably
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

As a note about routing.  IF you wanted to use `example.com/login` that is when you would map the route to the controller/method thusly: `$route['login'] ='users/login';`

#### Users Controller

```
class Users extends CI_Controller
{

    // routes to example.com/users/
    public function index() 
    {
       redirect('users/login');
    }     

     // routes to example.com/users/login
     public function login() {
         $data['title'] = 'Sign In';

         $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

         if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
             $this->load->view('templates/header');
             $this->load->view('users/login', $data);
             $this->load->view('templates/footer');
         } else {

             // Get username
             echo $username = $this->input->post('username');
             // disabled encryption for testing
             echo $password = $this->input->post('password');

             // Login user
             $user_id = $this->users_model->login($username, $password);

             if($user_id){
                 // Create session
                 $user_data = array(
                     'userID' => $user_id,
                     'username' => $username,
                     'logged_in' => true
                 );

                 $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

                 // Set message
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedin', 'You are now logged in');

                 redirect('users/welcome');
               } else {
                   // Set message
                   $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'Login is invalid');
                   redirect('users/failed');

                }
         }
    }

    // routes to example.com/users/welcome
    public function welcome() {
        $this->load->view('users/welcome');
    }

    // routes to example.com/users/failed
    public function failed() {
       $this->load->view('users/failed');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. QUICK DUMB QUESTION: So I create the methods and then I put my login code below the methods in the USER() controller?

Comment: Also would you mind giving me an example of how a route for this Controller should look like. Thanks a milliom

Comment: Your login code would be in the login method.  Routes you really don't need to do anything with....  Give me a few minutes and I'll expand my answer.

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee ok, take a look, I think I covered everything.